# react native firebase handle click action on push notification

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm working on my react native application and i'm sending push notifications using firebase :

in my component i imported librairies :

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
```

I add native configuration to receive notification in foreground and background mode for IOS and Android.

Now i want to add a click action to redirect to specific component .

I use Postman to send POST request with custom data :

```
    {
 "to" : "ceWTvUKphPk:APA91bG6CMyiHZfNnpIs76QyThECegzztWe5hjp05jrKU8ImyWwarprqRYFlY3Hry_Xbv0EV0W76PEgHf7ssMzJbaTOzGvmoZthZnWOm9ZGcpwtZ0ubcHY-ps-9yl-sdM-aGrh1bGbrn",
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "un nouveau partage",
 "title" : "un partage de contact reçu",
 "priority" : "high",
 "vibration":true,
 "sound": "Enabled",
 "badge":1,
 "requireInteraction": true,
 "click_action": "ACTION",
 },
 "data" : {
 "body" : "nouvelle opportunité",
 "title" : "un nouveau partage"
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 } 
}
```

How  can i create a click action and handle this action for both IOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think react native firebase cloud messaging don't support click action and we have to wait until the next update.

For more informations you can read this documentation :

[react native notifee documentation](https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/androidaction#notifee)